# Default login page little change

Tags: users

I want the following;
In the default login page, I want to delete this line:
[Nieuw wachtwoord aanvragen](/user/password) (Also DELETE "request new passord) on this site: http://www.deklotvaarders.nl/user

Also I don't want that users can request new password.
Where to do that?? Which file?

Thanks so much,
Greetz,
Pieter-Jan

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this is using hook_form_alter() with custom module. For example,

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register') {
    drupal_set_title(t('Create new account'));
  }
  elseif ($form_id == 'user_pass') {
    drupal_set_title(t('Request new password'));
  }
  elseif ($form_id == 'user_login') {
  drupal_set_title(t('Log in'));
  }
}
```

Comment: I found a module noreqnewpass-7.x-1.2. Works fine for me!! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found THE clue: There is a module: noreqnewpass-7.x-1.2. Works fine!!